# Clickatell - redirect after the sms sent

Tags: php, sms, clickatell

i want to integrate ang sms notification after the form was submitted, and after the sms sent i want to redirect it to my thankyou.html web page, this is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
$query="insert into table() values() ";
if(mysql_query($query)){
 header("location:http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=3549342&user=xxxx&password=xxxx&to=63926475xxxx&text=xxxx ");
}
}
?>
<form method=post >
Username: input type=text name=user >
Password: <input type=text name=pass >
Name: <input type=text name=name >
Mobile number: <input type=text name=mobile_no >
<input type=submit name=submit >
</form>
```

Suppose that the query returned true, it will send the sms, using the clickatell api, i want is if the message is success i want it to redirect on my .html page that display "Thank You".

I am new to this api, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function here to retrieve the contents of the api url?

```
<?php
  $url = "http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=3549342&user=xxxx&password=xxxx&to=63926475xxxx&text=xxxx";

  $data = file($url);

  $dataArr = explode(":",$data[0]);

  if ($dataArr[0] == "OK") 
  {
    //do the redirection here
    header("location:your.html");
    exit;
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo "Failed: ".$dataArr[1]; //apparently $dataArr[0] contains 'ERR' and has no details regarding the error.
  }
?>
```

You can see the entire content received with

```
print_r($dataArr);
```

Here is the link to [developer guide](https://www.clickatell.com/downloads/http/Clickatell_HTTP.pdf).

Comment: you should remove the "location:" from the $url variable

Comment: I tried it, it send ng message but it failed the redirection